# Advance search database query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables on MySQL database. "Products" and "Specifications". Products table contain information about products. And "Specifications" contain product specification. But specifications are dynamic, means, each product will have different types of specifications. I have shown some sample data below.

```
Products table
=============
id      name
---------------------
1       Product A
2       Product B


Specifications table
====================
id      product_id      spec_type       value
-------------------------------------------------
1       1               condition       new     
2       1               color           blue
3       1               size            large
4       2               condition       new
5       2               color           red
6       2               location        local
7       2               fragile         yes
```

Now when user search with "condition = new" both product A and B should come as the result. But when search "condition = new AND color = blue" then product A should come as a result.

I need help in building the SQL statement. I'm working on Laravel project, so if I get Laravel queries then it will be a bonus.

Comment: Did you build Models For "Products" and "Specifications"?

Comment: `specifications.condition` is mandatory search term/query and `products.name` is optional?

Comment: on "specification"... "spec type" will have different... not all product will have "condition". And all the product will have "name"

Answer (score 0):

You should use Eloquent relationships to easily achieve that

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function specifications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Specification::class);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Specification extends Model
{
    public function scopeSpecType($query, $specType)
    {
        return $query->where('spec_type', $specType);
    }

    public function scopeValue($query, $value)
    {
        return $query->where('value', $value);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

use App\Product;


$newProducts = Product::with(['specifications' => function ($query) {
    $query->specType('condition')->value('new');
}])->get();

$blueProducts = Product::with(['specifications' => function ($query) {
    $query->specType('color')->value('blue');
}])->get();
```

Comment: specifications are dynamic. We cannot have methods for each specification

Comment: the above query will work for one 'specType'... what about more specType ( condition = new AND color = blue ) ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already defined relationship between `Product` and `Specification`.

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    ...
    public function specifications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Specification::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Then you can apply multiple `whereHas` to Product query:

```php
// Use this one, both product A and B should come as the result
// $array = ['condition' => 'new']; 
// Use this one, product A should come as a result.
$array = ['condition' => 'new', 'color' => 'blue']; 

Product::where(function($query) use ($array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $val) {
        $query->whereHas('specifications', function($q) use ($key, $val) {
            $q->where(['spec_type' => $key, 'value' => $val]);
        });
    }
})->get();
```